# pdf file is not showing in device ionic

Tags: html, angularjs, pdf, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

After all search i have implemented pdf file view without download. But when i try to see my files.its not showing . Other than that all zoomin, zoomout, scroll, next page, front page all things are showing.Here my code :

```
<div  class="col col-50 clsGrid"  ng-click="showFile('http://www.orimi.com/pdf-test.pdf')">
</div>
```

**My controller :**

```
$scope.showFile = function(FileUrl) {
    var file = FileUrl;
    console.log(file);
     var openurl = cordova.InAppBrowser.open(file, '_blank');   
  }
```

Please help me out. how can i solve this.

thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

try this `var openurl = cordova.InAppBrowser.open(file,'_blank', 'location=no');`

Comment: @Edsion no its coming on white full screen and not showing any data

Comment: Code-only answers do very little to educate SO readers.  Please edit your answer to include some explanation. Your answer is in the moderation queue because it has been flagged as low-quality.

Comment: @Edison  hi, i have the requirement to show the pdf without download option for the user. i search over the internet . but not able to fount the solution. my post link is here. can you please help me out..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43496455/how-to-show-pdf-file-in-ionic-app-with-out-download    i tried more than 1 week. but not able to get. i am using ionic 1